# How to I bind controls in a UWP DataGrid Column Header template to instances of a class?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-community-toolkit

I'm trying to customise the header content of a [UWP DataGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid). I can add the necessary controls by changing the header style like [this](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues/3354#issuecomment-669824249), however I want to be able to bind the controls inside the template to instances of a class that are only available when the grid columns are (dynamically) created.

How do I make the binding in the code below valid (or another workaround)?

DataGrid example XAML:

```
<controls:DataGrid    
    x:Name="DataGrid"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ItemsSource}"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    ColumnHeaderHeight="80">

    <controls:DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="controlsprimitives:DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="controlsprimitives:DataGridColumnHeader">

                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

                            <TextBox Text="{x:bind PropertyOnMyClass, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

                            <!-- Some other controls -->

                        </StackPanel>

                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </controls:DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>

</controls:DataGrid>
```

Example of a column being added:

```
private void MakeColumn(MyClass classInstance)
{
    DataGridTextColumn column = new();
    column.Header = classInstance;
    DataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
}
```

I can add controls in the way above with no issue, and I can set the DataGridTextColumn Header property to the class instance and set the header text using a `GetString()` override on the class, but I can't find a way to bind to multiple properties.

A solution that creates the header controls in codebehind would also be fine, however you can't create Templates in codebehind.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, this is not possible. You could not assign a class to the header and try to bind to the class object. Generally, you could bind the controls in the ControlTemplate to the property of the code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my workaround was to call a method the first time the control loads to set the necessary links between the controls and the class:

XAML:

```
        <controls:DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <Style
            TargetType="controlsprimitives:DataGridColumnHeader">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="controlsprimitives:DataGridColumnHeader">
                            <ContentPresenter Loaded="HeaderLoaded"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </controls:DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
```

and code behind:

```
        private void HeaderLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var presenter = sender as ContentPresenter;
            if (presenter.DataContext is MyClassType myClassInstance)
            {
                presenter.Content = new ColumnHeader(myClassInstance, this);                
            }
            presenter.Loaded -= HeaderLoaded;
        }
```